# Is there a simple way to make multiple read commands instead of manually typing each out?

Tags: bash, loops

So i'm working on this program that will read in a file from the command line and use sed commands to replace certain patterns with things i wish to change. However i'm using a function that will read each line of the file then go into my assign2.sed file that will make the edits. For example, one file that i'm working with has 11 lines, shown below.

My question is, is there a much simpler way to read each line of the file instead of manually typing; read line1, read line2, and so on. Is it possible to make a for-loop/while loop that can loop until there's no more lines to be read?

```
#!/bin/bash

for numArguments in $@; do

function readFile() {
  read line1
  read line2
  read line3
  read line4
  read line5
  read line6
  read line7
  read line8
  read line9
  read line10
  read line11
}
readFile < $numArguments

sed -r -i -f assign2.sed $numArguments

done
```

Comment: Simply use `sed -r -i -f assign2.sed "$@"`. You don't need a function or loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and the syntax is as follows :

```
    while read VAR
    do
       #do something with line read into VAR
    done < input_file
```

However you can just do `sed -r -i -f assign2.sed "$@"` as sed can take multiple files as input.

Comment: Just a warning that using `read` in this way will treat  backslashes as escape characters, you may want to use it with the `-r` switch. Your question was also most likely down voted as this is clearly demonstrated in the man page for read ;).  (man is mans best friend)

Comment: So you think instead of my readFile function, use a while loop? I’ll try that then! And noted, I’ll try not to make the same mistake again next time!

Comment: Yeah, or you could use the loop within the function, whatever you feel makes the most sense. You could also just read once in your function, check that read sent back status 0 with `$?' And call the function again  recursively (if recursive functions are supported, I don't quite remember) , but I feel like the while loop is simplest.